# Updating Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have an old Vue 2 project that we are migrating to Vue 3, it had bootstrap which I ended up removing considering its old versions don't work really well with vue 3. Everything else seems fine except this error,

```
This dependency was not found:

* vue in ./src/main.js, ./src/api/store.js and 3 others

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue
```

I used vue update to update to vue 3, npm update to upgrade some dependencies, and had to use --legacy-peer-deps with the npm commads the first time, I had some errors which were removed after removing bootstrap imports from main.js. I have looked around, can't seem to find the solution for this, haven't worked with Vue3 a lot, any help would be appreciated thanks.

This is my main.js
[image]

This is me initializing app --- used to work before vue update

[image]

This is package.json vue
[image]

/Edit/

I changed import Vue to vue createApp, had some errors in terminal and terminal told me to update vue-loader to latest version, which I did and now I'm getting this error.
I have removed almost all of Vue.use items to make sure atleast app.vue loads and then I can move on from there. I'm following this tutorial

https://blog.logrocket.com/refactoring-vue-2-apps-vue-3/

[image: New errors]

I'm getthing this issue even though VueLoaderPlugin is in webpack config file

```
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
```

[image]

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing your case. If there's no `vue` dependency, it needs to be added. If it exists but it's not installed for some reasons, deps need to be reinstalled

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. What you posted so far cannot be used to repro, making your question unanswerable. Use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) or a similar service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply doesn't work like that anymore in Vue 3. `import Vue` and `new Vue()` have been replaced by:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const app = createApp(App);
```

Vue 3 isn't a drop-in replacement for Vue 2; there's a number of [breaking changes](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/) you should probably read up on.

Comment: As well as all of his other plugins he's using that might not have Vue3 versions